# Album Art sizes ARE NOT uniform in size (MVC Music Store)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am building a music store in ASP.NET using the mvc music store template:

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)

To add pictures to the album tiles you simply use a url to point to the album in the database. However, I can't make ALL the album art pictures UNIFORM in size. Some pictures are the proper size but others are too large.

[image]

I know code is used by the css site file but I'm not sure how to change the sizes. Any help, code, or links in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. This is the generic code that comes with the site.

```css
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to save a resized image, or just display the existing image at the correct size?

Comment: display an existing image. I just want all the album art to be the same size

Comment: In that case I'd remove everything about C#, ASP.NET, etc. and focus on the issue: HTML and CSS, and (maybe) JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to do modifications on the HTML code? If the answer is yes, an easy solution would be adding a CSS class to all the images, for example a `class="album-art-picture"` on every picture.

And then just go to your CSS file and and define the width to something like this:

```css
.album-art-picture {
    width: 300px
}
```